# hibernate class files are not loading through maven

Tags: hibernate, maven

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <name>JBoss repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

pom.xml file.

But My eclipse could not identify SessionFactory, Session,Transaction,HibernateException etc and gives compile time error. how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the repository URL you are using is correct. I get a 403 when accessing http://repository.jboss.org/maven2 
Have a look at the section "Configuring Maven to use the JBoss Repository" on the JBoss [Maven Getting Started](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users) page.

Once you have configured the correct repository try building your project outside of Eclipse. If it builds then you know the Maven project is configured correctly.

If you still have classpath issues inside your workspace after a successful build, try regenerating the eclipse settings files.

```
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

As of hibernate version 3.6, the core ja contains the annotations, so I don't believe you need an explicit dependency for annotations. Apart from that you shouldn't be getting compilation errors.

Comment: i am getting compile time error. Referenced Libraries from eclipse doesn't show hibernate.jar file.

Comment: Do you see the hibernate core jar file in your maven repository? I recently upgraded to 3.6.0.Final and never encountered any such problem.